# How to set flowplayer fullscreen option to false (not iframe)

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

Could you help me and answer how to set fullscreen in flowplayer to FALSE.

The code i use is:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
 $("#player").flowplayer({ 
    playlist: [ 
       [{ webm: "http://.../file.webm "},
       { mp4: "http://.../file.mp4 "}] 
    ]
 }); 
 });
```

And where and how i should write the option (fullscreen:false)?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable fullscreen mode for all players on a page by overwriting the default settings of the global flowplayer object. For your example, it would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //overwrites fullscreen: true in flowplayer.defaults
  flowplayer.config = { fullscreen: false; }

  $("#player").flowplayer({ 
    playlist: [ 
      [
        { webm: "http://.../file.webm"},
        { mp4 : "http://.../file.mp4 "}
      ] 
    ]
  }); 
});
```

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to change settings for individual players.

// edit: there actually is, as documented here: https://flowplayer.org/docs/setup.html#selective-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, Phil !! But your variant unfortunately doesn't work in my script((

The following script works:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
$("#player").flowplayer({
playlist: [
[{ webm: "http://.../file.webm "},
{ mp4: "http://.../file.mp4 "}] 
],
fullscreen: false,
tooltip: false
}); 
});</script>
```